# ¿Cómo cargar un archivo de jasper report desde una ruta absoluta? - Java

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Llevo unos días con este problema, tengo diseñado un reporte en la siguiente ruta `C:\Users\brynn\Desktop\SIET\report\InformeMensualLaboratorio.jrxml` y tengo el siguiente código donde trato de cargarlo al JasperReport:

```
final File file = new File(new File("").getAbsolutePath() + "/report/InformeMensualLaboratorio.jrxml");
final JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(file.getAbsolutePath());
final JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, new JREmptyDataSource());
final JasperViewer jasperViewer = new JasperViewer(jasperPrint, false);
jasperViewer.setModalExclusionType(ModalExclusionType.APPLICATION_EXCLUDE);
jasperViewer.setIconImage(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/View/icons/logo_ceretrop.png")).getImage());
jasperViewer.setTitle("SIET - Sistema de Información de Enfermedades Tropicales.");
jasperViewer.setVisible(true);
```

Cuando lo hago correr desde el NetBeans funciona perfectamente, pero cuando cuando construyo el `JAR` y lo hago correr desde ahí no funciona, sale el siguiente error:

> feb 06, 2021 9:20:34 AM View.GestionReportes.InformeMensualLaboratorio informeMensualGenerado
> GRAVE: null
> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error compiling report java source files : C:\Users\brynn\Desktop\SIET\InformeMensualLaboratorio_1612614034782_288790.java C:\Users\brynn\Desktop\SIET\InformeMensualLaboratorio_DataSetPrimeraTabla_1612614034782_288790.java C:\Users\brynn\Desktop\SIET\InformeMensualLaboratorio_DataSetSegundaTabla_1612614034782_288790.java C:\Users\brynn\Desktop\SIET\InformeMensualLaboratorio_DataSetTerceraTabla_1612614034782_288790.java C:\Users\brynn\Desktop\SIET\InformeMensualLaboratorio_DataSetCuartaTabla_1612614034782_288790.java C:\Users\brynn\Desktop\SIET\InformeMensualLaboratorio_DataSetQuintaTabla_1612614034782_288790.java C:\Users\brynn\Desktop\SIET\InformeMensualLaboratorio_DataSetSextaTabla_1612614034782_288790.java C:\Users\brynn\Desktop\SIET\InformeMensualLaboratorio_DataSetOctavaTabla_1612614034782_288790.java C:\Users\brynn\Desktop\SIET\InformeMensualLaboratorio_DataSetNovenaTabla_1612614034782_288790.java C:\Users\brynn\Desktop\SIET\InformeMensualLaboratorio_DataSetDecimaTabla_1612614034782_288790.java C:\Users\brynn\Desktop\SIET\InformeMensualLaboratorio_DataSetDecimaPrimeraTabla_1612614034782_288790.java C:\Users\brynn\Desktop\SIET\InformeMensualLaboratorio_DataSetSeptimaTabla_1612614034782_288790.java
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRJavacCompiler.compileClasses(JRJavacCompiler.java:106)
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractClassCompiler.compileUnits(JRAbstractClassCompiler.java:77)
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.compileReport(JRAbstractCompiler.java:201)
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compile(JasperCompileManager.java:354)
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compile(JasperCompileManager.java:340)
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JasperCompileManager.java:605)
> at View.GestionReportes.InformeMensualLaboratorio.informeMensualGenerado(InformeMensualLaboratorio.java:3051)
> at Presenter.GestionReportes.PresenterGestionReportes.obtenerInformeMensualLaboratorio(PresenterGestionReportes.java:52)
> at View.GestionReportes.InformeMensualLaboratorio$5.actionPerformed(InformeMensualLaboratorio.java:270)
> at javax.swing.JTextField.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
> at javax.swing.JTextField.postActionEvent(Unknown Source)
> at javax.swing.JTextField$NotifyAction.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
> at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.notifyAction(Unknown Source)
> at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBinding(Unknown Source)
> at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindings(Unknown Source)
> at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
> at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(Unknown Source)
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.Dialog.show(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.Component.show(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Unknown Source)
> at View.Principal.JMENUITEMInformeMensualLaboratorioActionPerformed(Principal.java:766)
> at View.Principal.access$2000(Principal.java:46)
> at View.Principal$20.actionPerformed(Principal.java:343)
> at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
> at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
> at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
> at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
> at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(Unknown Source)
> at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(Unknown Source)
> at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
> at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
> at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "javac": CreateProcess error=2, El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado
> at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
> at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
> at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRJavacCompiler.compileClasses(JRJavacCompiler.java:75)
> ... 95 more
> Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado
> at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
> at java.lang.ProcessImpl.(Unknown Source)
> at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
> ... 99 more

Según lo que entiendo es de que no se puede encontrar el archivo especificado y no se porque si la ruta donde se encuentra el archivo `InformeMensualLaboratorio.jrxml` sigue siendo la misma, lo único que cambio fue de que ya no lo estoy haciendo correr desde el NetBeans sino desde el ejecutable `JAR`.

Basándome en ese error lo que hice fue agregar el siguiente código debajo de la linea `final File file = new File(new File("").getAbsolutePath() + "/report/InformeMensualLaboratorio.jrxml");`:

```
final File file = new File(new File("").getAbsolutePath() + "/report/InformeMensualLaboratorio.jrxml");
if (file.exists()) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Existe");
} else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "No existe");
}
```

Y el mensaje que me muestra es de que el archivo existe, eso quiere decir que al momento de cargarlo al `File` si lo encontró y lo esta cargando, pero parece que el problema esta cuando ese archivo le paso al JasperReport, pero no estoy seguro, solo son suposiciones mías, porfavor que alguien me pueda ayudar con esto, ya llevo un buen tiempo estancado aqui.

Comment: Un jar es un zip. ¿Dónde esta el jrxml? ¿Dentro o fuera del jar(zip)? ¿Puedes acceder al contenido de un zip con una ruta absoluta?

Comment: El jrxml esta fuera del jar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que los archivos no son accesibles como tal (`File`) cuando empaquetas tu programa en un `.jar` ejecutable, sino que son accesibles **como recursos** (`InputStream`). Por eso, aunque la ruta esté bien, el archivo no será encontrado. Tienes que buscarlo como un recurso.

Entonces, olvídate de esto, lo cual funcionará sólo desde el IDE, como bien dices, pero desde un `.jar` no funcionará:

```
//No hagas esto para programas finales
final File file = new File(new File("").getAbsolutePath() + "/report/InformeMensualLaboratorio.jrxml");
```

Si accedes de este modo tu problema debería quedar resuelto, a no ser que haya otros problemas:

```
final JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/report/InformeMensualLaboratorio.jrxml"));
```

**PD:**
Aquí he usado una forma habitual de encontrar el archivo dentro de tu programa, pero si no tienes bien organizadas tus carpetas puede que el archivo no se encuentre en la ruta que se construye de forma automática mediante `getClass().getResourceAsStream()`. En ese caso, sugiero que organices bien tus carpetas de modo que los recursos puedan encontrarse de una forma segura, usando los métodos adecuados o bien que modifiques el código, poniendo la ruta a mano (NO RECOMENDADO).

Si tienes dudas sobre esto, te recomiendo la lectura de [este artículo](https://mkyong.com/java/java-read-a-file-from-resources-folder/), que ayudará a organizar los recursos y a referirte a ellos. Es una etapa fundamental, sobre todo cuando empaquetes el código para distribuirlo, porque, como has visto, en este caso concreto, no es lo mismo el entorno del IDE, que un `.jar` empaquetado.

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, te comento que anteriormente ya eh probado el modo que colocaste y de igual manera no puedo acceder al recurso tal como esta, tengo que cambiar de `.jrxml` a `.jasper` y recién puedo acceder, pero ahí se presenta otro problema y es de que me sale errores de codificación, me dice que el archivo no esta en `UTF-8` pero eso no es correcto ya que probé de todos lados y mi archivo tanto el .jrxml como el .jasper si están en UTF-8, además, uno de mis compañeros si pudo llamar al archivo .jrxml desde una ruta absoluta sin necesidad de cargarlo como un recurso.

Comment: @Leonidas no logro entender lo que ocurre al intentar así. ¿Encuentra el archivo sí o no? Ese era el problema,  según la traza de error que se lee en tu pregunta. Si lo encuentra entonces ESE problema está resuelto. Si ahora hay un problema de codificación deberías indicar cuál es el problema, y si abres una nueva pregunta para ello mejor, colocando igualmente la traza completa del nuevo error. Los problema de codificación pueden tener muchas causas y no se podrían analizar en simples comentarios. Siempre es fundamental ver la traza de error completa.

Comment: Aceptare esta respuesta acotando como parte de la solución el siguiente enlace: https://www.javaer101.com/es/article/3223356.html, resulta que en mi caso no era suficiente obtener el `jrxml` como recurso, sino que también debía colocar la dirección del `JDK` en las variables de entorno del sistema.

Answer (score 0):

Implementa estas lineas de codigo:

```
URL in = this.getClass().getResource("/Reportes/tu_reporte.jasper");
JasperReport jr= (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(in);
```